# How do i set Uploadcare's multiple upload field to give a array of URLs instead of a URL that references a group of images?

Tags: reactjs, forms, file-upload, multiple-file-upload, uploadcare

When `multiple = true`, Uploadcare gives an URL of group of images as value.
Is there any way that i can set to get a array of images URLs as value?

Answer (score 3):

there's no such option out of the box, but you can get an array of file URLs using the [JS API of the uploader](https://uploadcare.com/docs/file-uploader-api/):

```
// get a widget reference
const widget = uploadcare.Widget("[role=uploadcare-uploader]");

// listen to the "change" event
widget.onChange(async (group) => {
  const files = await Promise.all(group.files());
  const urls = files.map(file => file.cdnUrl);
  console.log(urls);
});
```

Here's how to implement the same if you're using [react-widget](https://github.com/uploadcare/react-widget):

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
import { Widget } from "@uploadcare/react-widget";

import "./styles.css";

const Example = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Widget
        publicKey="demopublickey"
        multiple
        onFileSelect={async (group) => {
          const files = await Promise.all(group.files());
          const urls = files.map((file) => file.cdnUrl);
          console.log(urls);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDom.render(<Example />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/uploadcare-react-widget-get-array-of-urls-from-multiupload-5si0y)

Also, you can access individual files in a group using the **/nth/** [URL directive](https://uploadcare.com/docs/delivery/cdn/#accessing-files). In this case, you don't have to know the "real" UUIDs of the files.